# XRandr GUI that supports Transform?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm trying to correct for keystone distortion using a small Ubuntu/Debian box and a projector. The intended effect is for the desktop to be distorted in a fashion similar to this:
[image: Keystone distortion]

This can be accomplished using the --transform option of xrandr; however, in order to achieve exact results in a reasonable amount of time, I need some sort of GUI to drag the edges of the screen into place.

I can't find an XRandr GUI that supports transformation. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: There is a python script kind of doing that https://github.com/qurn/xrandr-keystone-helper